# Database.ExecuteSprocAccessor() not mapping blob data correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, enterprise-library-5, data-access-app-block

If anyone can help me figure this out, I would greatly appreciate it.  For starters, I have a class like so:

```
public class Blob
{
    public int BlobID { get; set; }
    public string BlobName { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileMimeType { get; set; }
    public int FileSize { get; set; }
    public byte[] FileContent{ get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public int CreatedByProfileID { get; set; }
}
```

Pretty standard, it's just an object that maps to a table with the exact same field names.  The table in SQL Server looks like this:

[image]

My controller has add and view actions to do the reading and writing to the DB.  I can write the file fine, using the action code below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("dbconnstr");

        byte[] fileContent = new byte[file.ContentLength];
        file.InputStream.Read(fileContent, 0, file.ContentLength);

        object[] paramaters = 
        {
            file.FileName,
            file.FileName,
            file.ContentType,
            file.ContentLength,
            fileContent,
            DateTime.Now,
            12518
        };

        db.ExecuteNonQuery("sp_Blob_Insert", paramaters);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

But when I use the View action code below to read the file out to the browser, the FileContent field is always null:

```
public ActionResult View(int id)
{
    Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("dbconnstr");

    Blob blob = db.ExecuteSprocAccessor<Blob>("sp_Blob_SelectByPkValue", id).Single();

    return File(blob.FileContent, blob.FileMimeType, blob.FileName);
}
```

However, if I specifically map the field name, it works:

```
public ActionResult View(int id)
{
    Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("dbconnstr");

    IRowMapper<Blob> mapper = MapBuilder<Blob>.MapAllProperties().MapByName(x => x.FileContent).Build();

    Blob blob = db.ExecuteSprocAccessor<Blob>("sp_Blob_SelectByPkValue", mapper, id).Single();

    return File(blob.FileContent, blob.FileMimeType, blob.FileName);
}
```

Is this a bug with the ExecuteSprocAccessor() function?  Am I doing anything wrong?

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: have you found an answer? I'm having the same problem

Comment: I have not, and I am not having any luck googling either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
.Map(x => x.FileContent).WithFunc(ConvertVarBinaryToByteArray);
```

Then create function like this:

```
private static byte[] ConvertVarBinaryToByteArray(IDataRecord dataRecord) 
{ 
    return (byte[]) dataRecord.GetValue(dataRecord.GetOrdinal("FileContent")); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem this way:

Add this code before execute ExecuteSprocAccessor:

```
IRowMapper<FileEmail> rowMapper = MapBuilder<FileEmail>.MapAllProperties()
        .Map(x => x.MyFile)
        .WithFunc(ConvertVarBinaryToByteArray).Build();
```

And create the method how Russ said above:

```
private static byte[] ConvertVarBinaryToByteArray(IDataRecord dataRecord)
    {
        return (byte[])dataRecord.GetValue(dataRecord.GetOrdinal("FileContent"));
    }
```